# Kriging output does not make sense?

Tags: arcmap

I have used kriging on a dataset (point data) with default settings. I am wondering about the output I got, why is it that the majority of my output is defined as "orange"? Should it not be a bit more a mix between blue and red? For example shouldnt the area vest for the blue area be defined as blue?

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about kriging but my understanding is that there are no adequate default setting, to get meaningful result you need to do some prior data analysis to input the right parameter. See this ESRI page for more https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/how-kriging-works.htm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.